# Partial derivative of matrix-vector product

Tags: matrix-calculus

I have to compute the following:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A_p}} \sum_{p=1}^P \mathbf{A_p}\mathbf{y}(t-p), $$

with $\mathbf{A}$ being a matrix and $\mathbf{y}$ a vector. Do I have to write the matrix-vector product as a sum?

Comment: What are $A_p$?

Comment: @WillM. Hi. Basically each entry of A is a $n \times n$ matrix itself.

Comment: So, if $\mathrm{M}$ denote the space of square matrices or order $n,$ then $\mathbf{A} \in \mathrm{M}^\nu$ for $\nu = P$?

Comment: @WillM. I am not sure honestly. I am using least squares to estimate the entries of A (each $A_p$, for $p=1$ to $P$).

Comment: Please help others to help you by making questions as self contained as possible. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I think that this helps: if you have a linear transformation (like multipliying by a matrix), then "its derivative is itself", that is, if $f(h) = Ah,$ then $f'(v) = A$ for every $v.$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simple vector-valued function
$$\eqalign{
 f &= Ay \cr
}$$
or in index notation
$$\eqalign{
 f_i &= A_{ij}y_j \cr
}$$
Find its differential and gradient wrt $A$ 
$$\eqalign{
 df_i &= dA_{ij}\,y_j \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial A_{km}}
  &= \frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{km}}\,y_j \cr
  &= \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jm} \,y_j \cr
  &= \delta_{ik}\,y_m \cr
}$$
As expected, the gradient is a 3rd order tensor.

The funtion you are interested in is
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial}{\partial A_{q}}\,\,\sum_{p=1}^{N} A_p\,y(t-p) \cr
}$$
Assuming all of the $A_p$ are independent, only the $A_q$-term survives differentiation.

Apply the previous result by substituting 
$$\eqalign{
 A &\rightarrow A_q \cr
 y &\rightarrow y(t-q) \cr
}$$